# synchronize access to a static field

Tags: java, static, synchronization

in Item 67 of Effective Java by Josh Bloch, he mentioned that if a method modifies a static field, you must synchronize access to this field, as it's not possible for clients to perform external synchronization on such a method. I don't quite understand how come a client cannot perform external synchronization on a static method?

internal synchronization implementation:

```
public class Serial {
  private static int serialNumber = 0;

  public synchronized static void incSerial() {  
      serialNumber++;
  }

}
```

if no internal synchronization implemented, a client can synchronize externally:

```
synchronize(Serial.class) {

  Serial.incSerial();
}
```

any ideas?

Comment: btw, can you provide an exact quote, and let us know the page this is written. I would expect Bloch to be clear & correct

Answer (score 5):

A client can do that, but you can't force such a synchronization. So some client might do an unsynchronized access, and break everything.

Comment: well, the example would be trivial - one client syncrhonizes, the other doesn't. So multiple threads using the unsynchronized code is prone to synchronization issues

Comment: You can't force external synchronization for instance methods too.  I don't get special mention of static methods by Bloch here

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure that you use the lock associated with the class that holds the static instance variable.
If you acquire it with a synchronized block before and then call the static method, it's fine.
But you cannot enforce this on the client's code. They might forget or not be aware that the particular static variable is also used by other threads.
So enforcing it, like Bozho suggested, by synchronizing the static method and making the instance variable private would be the best approach.

Tiberiu

Comment: Guys one more important thing. In that quote Bloch has mentioned that "you must synchronize access to this field even if it is used by single thread". If its used by a single thread then why its needed to synhcronize?